# Angular UI-Router multiple views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular UI-Router. I have the following in my route config

```js
.config(function config($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('newsFeedView', {
      url: '/newsFeed',
      controller: 'newsFeedController',
      templateUrl: '../src/app/bulletinBoard/views/newsFeed.part.html',
      data: {
        pageTitle: 'News Feed'
      }
    })
    .state('tradeFeedView', {
      url: '/tradeFeed',
      controller: 'tradeFeedController',
      templateUrl: '../src/app/bulletinBoard/views/tradeFeed.part.html',
      data: {
        pageTitle: 'Trade Feed'
      }
    })
    .state('bulletinBoard', {
      url: '/bulletinBoard',
      views: {
        'tradeFeed': {
          url: "",
          controller: 'tradeFeedController',
          templateUrl: '../src/app/bulletinBoard/views/tradeFeed.part.html'
        },
        'newsFeed': {
          url: "",
          controller: 'newsFeedController',
          templateUrl: '../src/app/bulletinBoard/views/newsFeed.part.html'
        }
      },
      templateUrl: '../src/app/bulletinBoard/views/bulletinBoard.part.html'
    });
})
```

In my index page I just invoke the view using:

```
<div class="container" ui-view></div>
```

In My bulletinBoard.html i want to have a nested view:

```
<div ui-view="tradeFeed"></div>
<div ui-view="newsFeed"></div>
```

For the /newsFeed page and the /tradeFeed pages this works perfectly but for the bulletin board i can't see anything on the page. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I find the example on the official GitHub wiki to be very unintuitive. Here is a better one:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

For instance:

```
...

.state('bulletinBoard', {
    url: '/bulletinBoard',
    views: {

        // the main template will be placed here (relatively named)
        '': { templateUrl: '../src/app/bulletinBoard/views/bulletinBoard.part.html' },

        // the child views will be defined here (absolutely named)
        'tradeFeed@bulletinBoard': { template: ..... },

        // another child view
        'newsFeed@bulletinBoard': { 
            templateUrl: ......
        }
    }

});
```

The syntax of each view attribute being `viewName@stateName`.

Comment: tutorial link was just what i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Much better example than https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views.  This simplified my configuration from abstract state w/ child, which seems to be what the github wiki suggests.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Perfect, I'm using this to have two types of views (single - think no header, just full page login pages; and content - standard pages with headers and footers). **QUESTION:** is this a hacky setup or a WAD method?

Comment: How do I share the scope variables across these multiple views ?

Answer (score 10):

The `.state()` method's `templateUrl` is ignored when using the `views` object. See the ui-router wiki for more info:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#user-content-views-override-states-template-properties