# Angular.js - ui-router not injecting view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have a problem with ui-router for angular.js.
I am currently working on a project with angular.js and using ui-router as router.
The problem now is, that I want to have a nested view as like this:

**views/settings/index.html** (also an previously created template in ui-router)

```
<div class="settings">
  [...]
  <div class="settings-content" ui-view="content"></div>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
$stateProvider.state('settings', {
  url: '/settings',
  views: {
    main: {
      templateUrl: 'views/settings/index.html',
      controller: 'SettingsController'
    },
    "content": {
      templateUrl: 'views/settings/privacy.html',
      controller: 'SettingsController'
    }
  },
  ncyBreadcrumb: { label: 'Settings' }
})
```

Now the problem I have is, that the defined `content` template is not injected into the `ui-view="content"` div. The main content (`views/settings/index.html`) is loading properly. And in nested states it's also possible to add a template into the `ui-view="content"` with the same `"string": Object`.

How does this come?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any errors in the javascript console when you try to load the view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular UI-Router multiple views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175980/angular-ui-router-multiple-views)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `viewName@stateName` syntax as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23283912/61577).

Try this

```
$stateProvider.state('settings', {
  url: '/settings',
  views: {
    main: {
      templateUrl: 'views/settings/index.html',
      controller: 'SettingsController'
    },
    "content@settings": {
      templateUrl: 'views/settings/privacy.html',
      controller: 'SettingsController'
    }
  },
  ncyBreadcrumb: { label: 'Settings' }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the ui-router module in my demo application.

You need to specify the hierarchy in your view.

The parent view is not specified to child view so you must use ViewName@parentState

https://github.com/singhmohancs/angularDemo/tree/master/app/modules