# UI-Router multiple named views not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, multiple-views

I try to use the multiple named view of UI-Router but it's not working.

See following example to understand my problem :

**start.html**

```
<body ng-app="startApp">
    <div ui-view="navigation"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
</body>
```

**nav.html**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>btn1</li>
        <li>btn2</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**content.html**

```
<h1>My content</h1>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('startApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ngFileUpload', 'ngImgCrop'])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('start', {
        url: '/start',
        templateUrl: 'pages/start/start.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

        .state('start.Why', {
        url: '/Why',
        views: {
            'navigation@start': {
                templateUrl: 'pages/start/nav.html'
            },
            'content@start': {
                templateUrl: 'pages/start/content.html'
            }
        }
    })
})
```

**Problem**
Nothing is display. Nothing is injected in ui-view..
But if my ui-view hasn't name and my id view is `''` instead of `'navigation@start'` it's work : **navigation.html** is display..

I try with `'@start'` and without. I can't explain what is the problem. My js console is clear.

Can you help me, please ?

Comment: may be help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175980/angular-ui-router-multiple-views

Comment: Have you tried `navigation@start.why`?

Comment: I already try this, It's not working

Comment: is `start` state abstract?

Comment: i already try to put `start` state in abstract and change my start.why url in `/start/Why` with `start`state url in `''`

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/TWCQuoIyJRvTb42Z7xxe?p=preview
It's a similar problem

Comment: may be help u https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kp6ff28xoqghXRK0nlLs?p=preview)

What we need here, is to create *'start'* state's *unnamed* **view** placeholder `ui-view=""`, inside of the index.html:

```
<body ng-app="startApp">

    <div ui-view=""></div>
```

And the start's view will now not contain the ng-app

```
<!--<body ng-app="startApp">-->
<div>
  <h1>This is a start state view</h1>

  <div>place for child state views</div>
  <hr />
    <div ui-view="navigation"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
<!--</body>-->
</div>
```

That is it.. no other change. No root (start) has a target, and child (why) will be properly injected

Observe the current solution in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kp6ff28xoqghXRK0nlLs?p=preview)

Also check:

#### [Angular UI Router - Nested States with multiple layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25667660/1679310)

Comment: Yes ! It's working ! But now, in my different state as `start.Why`, my controller is never called.. For example, I have a `ng-click="start()"` button, before use nested views, it works but now, it's not the case... What I miss ?

Comment: That is the issue parent child.. if your next state e.g. start.Second is navigated from start.Why... parent stays as is - is not.. re-triggered. What you can do is to create special controller on child... I created example for you http://plnkr.co/edit/iZywAbe4DT5Fg0P5a7kW?p=preview

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow ;) Enjoy amazing UI-Router, sir

Answer (score 0):

as link i add for you.try this

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('start', {
    url: '/start',
    templateUrl: 'pages/start/start.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
})

    .state('start.Why', {
    url: '/Why',
    views: {
        'navigation@start.Why': {
            templateUrl: 'pages/start/nav.html'
        },
        'content@start.Why': {
            templateUrl: 'pages/start/content.html'
        }
    }
})
```