# UI-router with multiple views

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to learn the UI-Routing in AngularJS

I have two views. 1> The default and 2> When a button is clicked.

I have edited my code to use multiple views, however that doesn't seem to work. I am sure the code is not perfect but I cant find it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Code:

### HTML(index)

I have stacked all of my business in a single controller for the time being.

```
<div class="channels" ng-controller = "MainController">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">

      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="container2">
          <div class="channel_title container_title"> Channels </div>
            <channel-tab
              ........>
            </channel-tab>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-4" >
        <div class="container3">
          <div class="source_title container_source"> Sources </div>
          <div ui-view='DefaultSources' ></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="container4">
          <div class="keyword_title container_keyword"> Keywords </div>
          <div ui-view='DefaultKeywords'></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

### Route

```
angular.module('myApp').config(["$stateProvider", "$httpProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", function($stateProvider,$httpProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
$stateProvider.state('One',{
    views: {
      'DefaultSources@One':{
        url:'/Default_View',
        templateUrl:'/static/app/recommender_service/template/default_sources.html'
      },
      'DefaultKeywords@One':{
        url:'/Default_View',
        templateUrl:'/static/app/recommender_service/template/default_keyword.html'
      }
    }
})
}]).run(["$state", "$rootScope", function($state, $rootScope){
$rootScope.$state = $state;
}]);
```

Comment: Have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175980/angular-ui-router-multiple-views ?

Comment: Ya I did check, Even I user very similar code as given in the tutorial. However, that doesnt seem to work for me.  The route doesn't seem to work. I am unable to see my source and keyword panel using the ui-view