# ui router multiple named views are not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am not able to load my view while using the ui router here is my code sample-
Code for my router file -

```
angular.module('loginApp').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'USER_ROLES',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, USER_ROLES) {
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
      url: "/",
      views: {
        'nav': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/parts/nav.html'
        },
        'main': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
        }
      },
      data: {}
    });
  }
]);
```

Code for html view -

```
<div layout="column">
  <div ui-view="nav"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-if="currentUser"><b>Welcome</div>
    <div ui-view="main"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything *looks* right, but you don't explain what issue you are experiencing. Are you getting an error? Nothing is rendering? Only one view is rendering?

Comment: I am not getting any error. But no one my html file loading.

Comment: If you replace the `templateUrl` with just a `template: '<div>Nav</div>'` does that show up?

Comment: Ok I will try. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular UI-Router multiple views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175980/angular-ui-router-multiple-views)